# Manually parsing JSON before parsing to object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm creating a DSL based on JSON and JavaScript and I have a requirement to let key values be specified 'raw' and not enclosed in string delimiters. A quick example that hopefully explains this:

```
{myKey:custom_function('arg1'), myKey2:custom_function("another arg1")}
```

should become

```
{myKey:"custom_function('arg1')", myKey2:"custom_function(\"another arg1\")"}
```

This is because at the time of parsing the JSON object, custom_function will not exist. I need to be able to parse the JSON without evaluating any of the values, then only expand values one by one as I iterate the keys.

What regular expression or other method can I use to turn that 1st snippet into the 2nd one?

I'm assuming a simpler solution will cover 90% of cases but that writing a bullet-proof implementation would take a lot of effort. Based on the research I did into JavaScript's regular expression support (apparantly no lookbehind capability) I'm assuming it will require something more than just 1 or 2 lines of regex patterns.

Also, this is for a node application so any tricks that it has for this will be helpful too.

EDIT:

This question seems to be getting some downvotes, but I've left it up anyway for the benefit of future googlers / my own reference. It's a perfectly valid question about what method / technique would work best for this kind of problem, and there could easily be other node/js newcomers who face a similar problem.

Comment: Domain Specific Language. It's for a complex business case where users have a feature that lets them write scripts to instruct the application.

Comment: I feel the downvotes are due to your DSL being a hybrid JSON mockup, which doesn't make that much sense versus just using JSON as your DSL. Argue with management that the DSL should just be the JSON standard, points are that is is more maintainable, future-proof, easier to implement, la la la.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer: Regex just isn't suited to a task as complex as this. Any similarly complex solutions I found online (e.g. removing code comments) all resorted to a mainly custom, iterative approach, only using regex sparingly, so a similar approach ended up being not too painless in this situation.

So in the end the 'best' method I could find didn't involve very much regex or any specialized libraries from node or elsewhere suited to the problem.

Finally, for the benefit of future googlers who might have a similar problem, I've published my solution at https://gist.github.com/2590689 and copied below:

```
//clothe a hub file that has 'naked' expressions
//e.g. turn {key:$('body p')} into {key:"$('body p')"}
function clothe(contents){

closers = /[\}\]\)\/"']/
openers = /[\{\[\(\/"']/
closing = {
    "{": "}",
    "[": "]",
    "(": ")",
    "/": "/",
    '"': '"',
    "'": "'"
}

contents = contents.split("");

var beforeKey = true;
var inKey = false;
var beforeValue = false;
var inValue = false;
var inArray = false;
var delimiterStack = [];

function inDelimited(){
    return delimiterStack.length > 0;
}

function toggleDelimiter(d){
    if(openers.exec(d) && !closers.exec(d)){
        pushDelimiter(d);
    }else if(openers.exec(d) && closers.exec(d)){
        if(topDelimiter()){
            if(topDelimiter()==d){
                popDelimiterIfValid(d);
            }else{
                pushDelimiter(d);
            }
        }else{
            pushDelimiter(d);
        }
    }else if(closers.exec(d)){
        popDelimiterIfValid(d);
    }
}

function topDelimiter(){
    if(delimiterStack.length>=0){
        return delimiterStack[delimiterStack.length-1];
    }else{
        return undefined;
    }
}

function pushDelimiter(d){
    delimiterStack.push(d);
}

function popDelimiterIfValid(d){
    if(delimiterStack.length>0)
        if(closing[delimiterStack[delimiterStack.length-1]]==d)
            delimiterStack.pop(d);
}

function rTrimmedRightBound(rightBound){
    while(rightBound>0){
        if(!/\s/g.exec(contents[--rightBound])){
            return rightBound+1;
        }
    }
}

for(var i=0; i<contents.length; i++){

    function delimiterCheck(c){
        if(c=='"'){
            toggleDelimiter('"');
            contents.splice(i, 0, '\\');
            i++;
        }else if(openers.exec(c) || closers.exec(c)){
            toggleDelimiter(c)
        }
    }

    if(beforeKey){
        if(/[a-zA-Z0-9$_!]/.exec(contents[i])){
            beforeKey = false;
            inKey = true;
        }
    }else if(inKey){
        if(contents[i]==":"){
            inKey = false;
            beforeValue = true;
        }
    }else if(beforeValue){
        if(/[a-zA-Z0-9$_!'"\(\/]/.exec(contents[i])){
            contents.splice(i, 0, '"');
            i++;
            beforeValue = false;
            inValue = true;
            delimiterCheck(contents[i]);
        }else if(/\{/.exec(contents[i])){
            beforeKey = true;
            beforeValue = false;
        }else if(/\[/.exec(contents[i])){
            beforeValue = false;
            inArray = true;
        }
    }else if(inArray && !inValue){
        if(/[a-zA-Z0-9$_!'"\(\/]/.exec(contents[i])){
            contents.splice(i, 0, '"');
            i++;
            beforeValue = false;
            inValue = true;
            delimiterCheck(contents[i]);
        }
    }else if(inValue){
        if(!inDelimited() && /[\},\]]/.exec(contents[i])){
            contents.splice(rTrimmedRightBound(i), 0, '"');
            i++;
            inValue = false;
            if(/\]/.exec(contents[i])){
                inArray = false;
            }
            beforeKey = !inArray;
        }else{
            delimiterCheck(contents[i]);
        }
    }
}

return contents.join("");
}
```